# Алгоритм обработки пакетных данных php sql

Tags: php, sql, post

Задача передать через пост массив данных, и сохранить в таблицу соответствующее множество записей. Предварительно эти данные нужно запросить, для внесения изменений в существующие. Как с точки зрения производительности правильно это реализовать:
1) при получении POST найти соответствующие записи , обновить их, а потом уже добавить несуществующие.
2) удалить все старые записи и добавить по новой все записи с ПОСТА.

второй вариант мне кажется проще, и правильнее. Но задача стандартная, уверен что есть уже оптимальный шаблон реализации.

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет решение из этого [топика](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте конструкцию INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

```
INSERT INTO ins_duplicate VALUES (4,'Gorilla') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE animal='Gorilla';
```

в этом случае будут вставлены записи c новыми ключами, и обновлены записи с ключами которые уже есть в БД